# How to get Distinct Records from Temp table to Sql one database table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i have temp table named `"#Test"` which have columns `"T1", "T2", "T3"` with data.
I have database table named "TestTbl" which have same columns.
I want to insert data from `#Test` table to `TestTbl` with distinct records of `T1` column.
Do you have any idea how to insert distinct records in `TestTbl` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You Can Try Like this....

```
INSERT INTO TestTbl (T1,T2,T3)  SELECT T1,T2,T3 from
(
Select Row_Number() over(Partition By T1 order By T1) as row,* from #Test
) a
 where a.row=1;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO TestTbl (T1,T2,T3)
SELECT Distinct(T1), T2, T3 FROM #Test
```

EDIT After further explanation

```
INSERT  INTO TestTbl
        ( T1 ,
          T2 ,
          T3
        )
        SELECT  T1 ,
                T2 ,
                T3
        FROM    ( SELECT    T1 ,
                            T2 ,
                            T3 ,
                            Row_Number() OVER ( PARTITION BY T1 ORDER BY T1) AS record
                            -- you need to select the relevant clause here for the order
                            -- do you want first or latest record? 
                  FROM      #Test
                ) tmp
        WHERE   tmp.record = 1 ;
```

Comment: for e.g. i have two rows in TestTbl (1) '1','2','3', (2) '1','4','5'. I need only first record with distinct table. I have duplicate data only in T1 column but other column may have different data. I need top 1 record.

Comment: When you say first record, you mean the first instance of T1 = n? if so, this should work.

Answer (score 0):

Get distinct records

```
SELECT DISTINCT column_name,column_name
FROM table_name
```

Insert records

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...)
```